# Google Sheets import multiple HTML table images

Tags: google-sheets

**Summary**

I'm looking to import a data table from a website that does not appear to have an API. The table is broken down to various images and text. The goal is to have all of the content available in a table to then reference for other sheets.

**Issue**

When I pull in the data, I get some of the text, none of the other images, and a reference to another table. I looked up some options, but none of them yielded anything but blank cells.

I also tried to use the `=IMAGE()` formula with a direct link to the images URLs, but there is a portion of the URL that is specific to the unit's release date, and as such, too dynamic to account for.

[image: Example Output]

**Excel Formula**

`=IMPORTHTML("https://gamepress.gg/pokemonmasters/database/sync-pair-list","table",3)`

Comment: Can you provide the result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately without an API it is going to be difficult to achieve what you aim here. These are the main reasons why:

## PROBLEMS AND WORKAROUNDS

- This table has nested tables that therefore need to be accessed separately. If you take a look at: `=IMPORTHTML("https://gamepress.gg/pokemonmasters/database/sync-pair-list","table",4)`
   you will see how the table 4 of this HTML page is the stats of a random character of the main table. If you go for 5 or 6 you will realise that the nested tables are not even numerically ordered and that you cannot access them by accessing to the main table (i.e `mainTable[0].nestedTable`). A hard working approach to do this is to go one by one finding their corresponding stat table and placing next to it. For this I recommend extracting only the name field of the main table to be able to align each stat to their character. You can simply do this using:`=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://gamepress.gg/pokemonmasters/database/sync-pair-list","table",3),0,1)`. You can find out more about `INDEX` [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- IMPORTHTML cannot access images nor links so it will be very difficult to get the images in the last columns. A way to solve this is by using as you mentioned the image with its url like this: `=IMAGE("https://gamepress.gg/pokemonmasters/sites/pokemonmasters/files/styles/30x30/public/2019-07/Electric.png?itok=fkRfkrFX")`. You can find more info about inserting images [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en)

## CONCLUSION

To sum up, there is no easy way to solve this problem. The closest you can get is by:

1. Importing the name column.
2. Figuring out which tables belong to which character and placing them with next to their name.
3. Getting the image url of each weakness and type and add it to each character.

I am sorry this site does not have an API to make things smooth, good luck with your project and let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understand anything.

[Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) you can find more information about **IMPORTHTML**

Comment: Fantastic information. Thank you. Is this possible through appscript? I don't mind running a macro do to this, but i just want to know if I still choosing a very challenging path.

Comment: yes indeed, all this can be done through Apps Script, you can get more about their Sheets documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet). Let me know if you need any help with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is possible, but the page you're importing from uses javascript to populate the table at runtime so when you use ImportHTML or ImportXML the table is empty. This might not have been true when you posted though. To get around that open dev tools in your browser copy the html and paste it somewhere you can get a link to.

The other problem is you are using ImportHTML instead of ImportXML. If you import the page as xml you can use XPath queries to get the data you want.

First, pull the text fields and blank images into your data sheet. For example `ImportHTML("https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Hisui_Pok%C3%A9dex_number", "table")` in A1 gets me all the data except the image column and the hyperlink in the Pokemon column.

To get the hyperlink to the pokemon's page we'll use ImportXML
`ImportXML("https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Hisui_Pok%C3%A9dex_number", "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[8]/a/@href")`. The XPath query could be simpler, but this lazy way works pretty good. [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) is how you select what data from the document you want to retrieve. Just work your way down the element tree until you get to your rows and select the column you want by number.

Unfortunately this only gives us a relative link so we also need to use ArrayFormula and possibly Hyperlink depending on your actual data. Put this in L2.

```
ArrayFormula(
  Hyperlink(
    "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/" &
    ImportXML(
      "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Hisui_Pok%C3%A9dex_number",
      "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[8]/a/@href"
    )
  )
)
```

For the image itself we need to do something similar. Pull the src attribute from the right img tag and feed it to Image. Put this in M2.

```
ArrayFormula(
  Image(
    ImportXML(
      "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Hisui_Pok%C3%A9dex_number",
      "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr//td/following-sibling::th/a/img/@src"
    ),
    4,
    64,
    64
  )
)
```

After that, resize your cells to fit the data and add headers in L1 and M1. If you want to save a copy of everything select it all, copy, and then paste as "Values Only".